# Python-Docx missing default template

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I recently installed the python-docx package and I'm having some trouble with the default template. I'm just setting up a document and have the following code (in a file called maintitle.py):

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Desktop/Python/maintitle.py", line 4, in <module>
    document = Document()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docx/api.py", line 25, in Document
    document_part = Package.open(docx).main_document_part
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docx/opc/package.py", line 128, in open
    pkg_reader = PackageReader.from_file(pkg_file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docx/opc/pkgreader.py", line 32, in from_file
    phys_reader = PhysPkgReader(pkg_file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docx/opc/phys_pkg.py", line 31, in __new__
    "Package not found at '%s'" % pkg_file
docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docx/templates/default-docx-template'
```

Taking a look in the directory "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docx/templates" there are only four files:

```
default-footer.xml  default-settings.xml
default-header.xml  default-styles.xml
```

I installed python-docx with pip3 install python-docx. Should I do something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a problem in release v0.8.9 that raised this error in certain environments. If you install v0.8.10 this should go away.

```
$ pip install python-docx==0.8.10
```

In some Ubuntu and possibly Mint distributions having an older setuptools version, you may also need to update `setuptools`:

```
$ pip install -U setuptools
```

For whatever reason, those distributions have a v20.x setuptools where the latest is v40.x.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but after using the below command everything looks good.

Use:

```
pyinstaller --collect-data "docxcompose" --onefile d:\python\Merge_Docx.py
```

instead of:

```
pyinstaller --onefile d:\python\Merge_Docx.py
```

(d:\python\Merge_Docx.py  is the python script located)