# How to use PIP to install python-docx?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, python-docx

I entered the following command into the terminal on my Mac: `sudo pip install python-docx --user` . Things happen, and stuff pops up and down like crazy in the terminal. All of a sudden... an error! It's kinda irking me. The following comes up:

```
   error: can't copy 'docx/templates/default-docx-template': doesn't exist or not a regular file

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-NbCMpP/python-docx/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-rulxzG/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-NbCMpP/python-docx/
```

All I want is for docx to show up in my damn Lib file in Pycharm. Why do bad things happen to good people? Thanks in advance. I'm a complete beginner, so pretend you're talking to a five-year-old.

Comment: Have you read through this? https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/594

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101831/python-docx-missing-default-template/54138423#54138423

Answer (score 0):

When you run `pip install` with the `--user` flag, the package is installed in your user directory ([as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989020/4484019)). Because of that, you don't need superuser privileges and don't need to use `sudo`.

You can run just:

`pip install python-docx --user`

And probably will work fine (I tested in my Mac and worked well).

Comment: I tried it, and I got the same error :/ `Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/mp/k648gswj25l_jfkdxh1_w7t00000gn/T/pip-install-voM14L/python-docx/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/mp/k648gswj25l_jfkdxh1_w7t00000gn/T/pip-record-TG24l2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/mp/k648gswj25l_jfkdxh1_ ... etc`

Comment: Did you see the issue commented by Jordan Singer?
Try to update the setuptools package : `pip install -U setuptools`